# network interface speed on windows using python

Tags: python, windows, networking, network-programming

I'm writing an app in python for windows and I want to know the speed of a network interface in my machine, I use the following code to get the routing table used.

```
def cmd(c):
    """
    Execute commands in the command line
    """
    return os.popen(c).read().rstrip("\n")

#list of IPV4 network routs 
table = cmd("route print -4").split("\n")
```

And then I process `table` as a string, cut it into lines, and get a list of `(ip, subnet, gateway, metric)` tuples for each interface.

Is there a way to calculate the speed of the connection to the internet using an interface? or a command to get such information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged the amount of traffic going through each interface and made a timer to calculate the speed of each one.